# Existence of a continuous function out of a metric space with specific properties

Tags: general-topology, continuity

In a paper I am reading, the existence of a function as described below is claimed with no explanation. I can not figure out why such a function should exist. Can someone tell? Urysohn's lemma does not seems helpful in this situation.

Consider a metric space $X$ and two subspaces $U, V$ such that $\mathsf{int}\,U \cup \mathsf{int}\,V = X$. There exists a continuous function $f: X \to [0, 1]$ such that $$\mathsf{cl}\, \{x \in X: f(x)<1\}\subset V \quad \text{ and }\quad \mathsf{cl}\, \{x \in X: f(x) >0 \}\subset U$$
Just to point out, in the case of interest the intersection $W=U \cap V$ will be non empty.

Answer (score 0):

We need $f(U \setminus V) = 0$ and $f(V \setminus U) = 1$. This implies that we need $f(\overline{U \setminus V}) = 0$ and $f(\overline{V \setminus U}) = 1$, and so we would then by done by Urysohn's lemma. In other words, the condition $\overline{U \setminus V} \cap \overline{V \setminus U} = \emptyset$ is necessary and sufficient for such $f$ to exist.

On the other hand (Kavi beat me to it!): If $\operatorname{int} U \cup \operatorname{int} V = X$ then $V \setminus U = X \setminus U$, and so $\overline{V \setminus U} = \overline{X \setminus U} = X \setminus \operatorname{int} U$ (the closure of a complement is the complement of the interior). Likewise $\overline{U \setminus V} = X \setminus \operatorname{int} V$, so $\overline{U \setminus V} \cap \overline{V \setminus U} = (X \setminus \operatorname{int} V) \cap (X \setminus \operatorname{int} U) = \emptyset$, as desired.

Comment: Your condition is satisfied because every point of $X$ belongs to interior of $U$ or interior of $V$.